# create user in team foundation server 2012

Tags: tfs, tfs-2012

Is there a way to create users in team foundation not using windows users? what I understand  users who can access the team project is those whose account is created in windows( I am using windows seven:it hosts the team foundation server).

What I want is to have users of team foundation server only without using windows to create them.

Answer (score 0):

No: TFS is based on Windows Authentication, every account is a Windows account.